# Regular expression doesn't match like I want

Tags: c#, regex

So, I got an regular expression :

```
(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])
```

That should found all letters and replace it with a blank.

```
var nomDoc = Regex.Replace(arr[0], "(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[0-9])", " ");
```

But when I got for example :

`45a, nomDoc` become `45 a`, while I juste want `45`

Did I write this regex wrong? I'm not very good at it, but I was thinking I was good for this one.

The regex must replace all non-numeric characters, following a numeric character or all non-numeric char before numeric.

45a or a45 must give me 45.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you create a JSFiddle so we can test and help fixing your issue ?

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: If you replace with *blanks* (single whitespace characters) rather than an empty string, how can you expect the result to be just `45`, without any blank, after replacing the non-numerical characters?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to replace anything non-numeric with one space per character. So why don't you just replace every occurrence of `[^0-9]` with ` `?

Comment: @Me123 a regex still a regex, whatever the language right? The important part is the regex, not the replace. n.st : forgot : all non-numeric, following numeric .

Comment: @n.st because my string isn't just 45a but 45a title - some text. So here, I just want to obtain 45 title - some text.

Comment: @Zaphod Some differ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973343/regular-expressions-same-for-all-languages

Comment: @Theox Why would you ask for a JSFiddle in a non-javascript question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing, is searching for a spot where the string changes from digits to letters or from letters to digits and insert a space there. So yes, `45a` becomes `45 a`.

If you want to replace all letters with a blank, use

```
 var nomDoc = Regex.Replace(arr[0], "[A-Za-z]", " ");
```

But I doubt that this is what you want.
If you want to *remove* all letters, replace with an empty string instead of a space.

If you want to replace all letters following a digit with a space, use

```
var nomDoc = Regex.Replace(arr[0], "(?<=[0-9])[A-Za-z]+", " ");
```

Comment: So, if I want to replace all letters following a digit or to replace all letters preceding a digit I use :  `(?<=[0-9])[A-Za-z]+ | [A-Za-z]+(?<=[0-9])` ?

Comment: Basically yes, but you'll need to omit the spaces (unless you want to remove them too).

Comment: No, I juste write them like this, but `(?<=[0-9])[A-Za-z]+|[A-Za-z]+(?<=[0-9])` will be more correct for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = "1 oo 23ksls 4910fsj2jd43ld fkkd ^&?&;@";
var nomDoc = str.Replace('/([^0-9]|\n)/g', ' ');
```

This replaces all the non-number characters(letters, whitespaces and characters) with a space.

Comment: You seem to be missing the string on which you want to perform the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
var nomDoc = Regex.Replace(arr[0], "[^0-9]", "");
```

If you are using Javascript, here's a fiddle :

```
var Str = "blablabla22445543__-_-_-_-_-_-èèpzofez5zsqef*f-e+ffnfuf'3";

var nomDoc = Str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

$("#result").html(nomDoc);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqF6L/

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear if you want to replace all non-numeric characters with spaces or just remove then completely.

Depending on that, either

```
var nomDoc = Regex.Replace(arr[0], "[^0-9]", " ");
```

or

```
var nomDoc = Regex.Replace(arr[0], "[^0-9]", "");
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

hey if you want to remove all your words then use below format method

var demo= Regex.Replace(arr[0], "(?<=[0-9])[A-Za-z]+", " ");