# Regex differences between Kotlin and Swift

Tags: android, ios, swift, regex, kotlin

I have an application implemented in Android with Kotlin and in iOS with Swift.

I want the backend to send with a response to the clients a regular expression. This regular expression must then be checked in both apps in order to see if it matches a user's input.

**Question:**
Do regular expressions have the same syntax in both Kotlin and Swift? If not, what are their differences?

Comment: Swift uses the [ICU](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/) regex engine. I have no idea what kotlin uses, maybe it is the same as [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)?

Comment: 100% sure you will need to test them on both platforms

Comment: ICU regex used in Kotlin is not the same as `java.util.regex`. There are differences, there are a lot of similarities.

Comment: Edited the question to have a more focused content and only a very specific question to avoid any confusion.

Comment: "*Do regular expressions have the same syntax in both Kotlin and Swift? If not, what are their differences?*" is still too broad. If you can supply a specific test case that you have trouble with, please share to make this question answerable.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this question is as broad as these similar questions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973343/regular-expressions-same-for-all-languages) & (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739633/regex-standards-across-languages) and others, that have been allowed and have helpful answers with great information and resources.
Also, for anyone who needs it, I found out that ICU and Java regex have these differences (https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html#differences-with-java-regular-expressions). So, my question is answerable as well and should be reopened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone who may have the same question, after some research, I came to the conclusion that **Swift** uses [ICU](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/) for regular expressions, while **Kotlin** is using the regular expression syntax that **Java** uses and has [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) pattern syntax.

You can find the exact **differences between ICU and Java** regular expressions [here](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html#differences-with-java-regular-expressions).